# Compare two arrays and merging in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1=>1,10=>1,12=>0,13=>13);
$array2 = array(1=>"Hello",10=>"Test",12=>"check",13=>"error");
```

Here $array1 has keys and values. Now I want to take the first value from $array1(as 1) and I want to check if this is repeated in this array .

Here 1 is repeated two times so I want to take the two keys 1,10 and display the corresponding values of these keys from $array2. If the value in $array1 is not repeated  then I want to just display the value of this key from $array2.

I want to get the output as follows:

```
Hello Test
check
error
```

That means in $array1 1,10 keys have the same value so the value of 1 and the value of 10 from $array2 is merged then displayed.

Like 12 has 0 this is not repeated so simply take value of 12 from $array2.

Like 13.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really rough, but a simple way of doing it could be:

```
<?

$array1 = array(1=>1,10=>1,12=>0,13=>13);
$array2 = array(1=>"Hello",10=>"Test",12=>"check",13=>"error");

$prev = $array1[1];

foreach($array1 as $key => $val)
{
    if($val != $prev && $key != 1)
    {
        echo '<br />';
    }

    echo $array2[$key].' ';

    $prev = $val;
}

?>
```

Example: http://codepad.org/OpLdtStp

This assumes that you're first key is always going to be `1` by the way.

Comment: You're right, but given the question and what's he's trying to do, I'm assuming the orders will be the same. He didn't specify that they would change.

Comment: Can you put an example up that might be in a different order?

Comment: $array1 = array(1=>1,10=>0,12=>1,13=>0);
$array2 = array(1=>"Hello",10=>"Test",12=>"check",13=>"error");

Comment: $array1 = array(1=>0,10=>1,12=>0,13=>0);
$array2 = array(1=>"Hello",10=>"Test",12=>"check",13=>"error");

Comment: This are differnt orders it may any order

Comment: If you're changing the order of the array, then your changing the way you want it laid out, yes? If thats the case, then this still works... http://codepad.org/J8kDPitp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9851/discussion-between-kichu-user-and-ben-griffiths)

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

$array1 = array(1=>1,10=>1,12=>0,13=>13);
$array2 = array(1=>"Hello",10=>"Test",12=>"check",13=>"error");
$groupedKeys = array();
foreach($array1 as $key=>$arr){
   $groupedKeys[$arr][] = $key;
}
foreach($groupedKeys as $key => $groupedKeyArr){
    foreach($groupedKeyArr as $groupedKey){
        echo $array2[$groupedKey];
    }
    echo "<br /> ";
}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/9R9s5lTM

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in function that returns an array with the number of times a value is repeated http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you a function returns an array with the number of times a value is repeated in an array(as values) and values as the keys. Further task is not difficult.

```
function check_number_of_times_elements_occur_in_array($a)//returns values of array as keys, associating values being their total occurences in the array
{
$r=array();
foreach($a as $v)
    ++$r[$v];
return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do for you..

```
function test($array1,$array2) {
$repeated_values = array_count_values($array1);
foreach($repeated_values as $key => $value){
    if($value > 1) {
        foreach($array1 as $key1 => $value1){
            if($key == $value1){
                $repeated_values_keys[] = $key1;
            }
        }
    }
}
$str_top = "";
foreach($repeated_values_keys as $k){
    $str_top .= $array2[$k]." ";
}
echo $str_top.'<br/>';
foreach($array2 as $key2 => $value){
    if(!in_array($key2,$repeated_values_keys)){
        echo $value.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

}